# Crashlytics doesn't see NDK kit

Tags: android, android-ndk, crashlytics

I integrated Crashlytics into Android app with C++ parts (made with Cocos Creator). Crashes in Java (`Crashlytics.getInstance().crash()`) logged just fine and they are visible in Firebase Crashlytics console. But crashes in C++ are not detected. So I followed [instructions to turn on Crashlytics detailed logs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/force-a-crash?platform=android) and noticed that NDK kit is missing from the list of kits that Crashlytics initialized with:

```
06-06 19:13:55.241  9174  9174 D CrashlyticsCore: Exception handling initialization successful
06-06 19:13:55.242  9174  9174 D Fabric  : Initializing io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric [Version: 1.4.8.32], with the following kits:
06-06 19:13:55.242  9174  9174 D Fabric  : com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers [Version: 1.4.7.32]
06-06 19:13:55.242  9174  9174 D Fabric  : com.crashlytics.sdk.android:beta [Version: 1.2.10.27]
06-06 19:13:55.242  9174  9174 D Fabric  : com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics [Version: 2.10.1.34]
06-06 19:13:55.242  9174  9174 D Fabric  : com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core [Version: 2.7.0.33]
06-06 19:13:55.242  9174  9174 D Fabric  :
06-06 19:13:55.253  9174  9245 D CrashlyticsCore: Opening a new session with ID ...
```

./build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ....
    dependencies {
        ....
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.29.0'
    }
    ....
}
```

./app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
...
crashlytics {
    enableNdk true
}
...
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:2.1.0'
    ...
}
```

**UPDATE**

NDK disappears from kits list when I use

```
<meta-data android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled" android:value="false" />
```

and later initialize it with

```java
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
```

in order to get user's consent first for GDPR compliance.

Should I initialize Crashlytics NDK kit from C++ via JNI in that case?

Comment: Fabric/Firebaser here - if you check your crashlytics.log, are you able to see any information about NDK, symbol generation, or symbol upload? That's a reliable to way to see if you're actually initializing the NDK kit. That log will be located here:

On Linux / Windows:~/.crashlytics/com.crashlytics.tools/crashlytics.log

On Mac:~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics/com.crashlytics.tools/crashlytics.log

Comment: @KevinKokomani Hi! There is none if I just do `assembleDebug`. It's only there if I'll manually do `crashlyticsUploadSymbolsDebug` - but APK is already built at that stage.

I'll try to build small sample project at the Monday and notify you.

Comment: @KevinKokomani Hi. I've narrowed things down to postponed initialization (see original post' update) but still don't know how to fix it in that case.

Comment: Thanks! You do have to kick off each new build with a symbol upload task similar to 'crashlyticsUploadSymbolsDebug' - our plugin will attempt to find the paths to your binaries, generate symbols on them, and then upload them to our server. Can you try enabling with Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics(), new CrashlyticsNdk()); instead of your current init statement?

Comment: @KevinKokomani That worked thanks. I posted my answer and home Firebase/Crashlytics will update the docs to clarify that moment of "opt-in reporting"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you postpone Crashlytics initialization to acquire users's consent using

```xml
<meta-data android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled" android:value="false" />
```

then to activate ndk-kit later you have to explicitly enlist it as an argument to `Fabric.with`:

```java
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics(), new CrashlyticsNdk());
```

I hope Firebase/Crashlytics will update "opt-in reporting" section of the documentation to mention that.